WP Query: orderby with one meta key, but multiple values
I'm trying to order a wp_query using one custom field. It is a radio group with three values: G, S and B (These represent Gold, Silver and Basic). I've been following the documentation and have looked on forums but I can't get this to cooperate. I just want to show Gold, then Silver, then Basic. No matter what I try, it puts Silver results before Gold. My code looks like this:
  $supplierArgs = array(
'post_type' => 'service_providers',
'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  'list_tier_gold' => array(
    'key'     => 'service_provider_tier',
    'value'  =>  'G',
    'compare' => '=',
  ),
  'list_tier_silver' => array(
    'key'     => 'service_provider_tier',
    'value'  =>  'S',
    'compare' => '=',
  ),
  'list_tier_basic' => array(
    'key'     => 'service_provider_tier',
    'value'  =>  'B',
    'compare' => '=',
  ),
),
'orderby' => array(
    'list_tier_gold' => 'DESC',
    'list_tier_silver' => 'DESC',
    'list_tier_basic' => 'DESC',
),

);

You can use the IN comparison, this will allow you to pass an array as a value

Use this code instead-
$supplierArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'service_providers',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'service_provider_tier',
            'value'   => 'G',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'service_provider_tier',
            'value'   => 'S',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'service_provider_tier',
            'value'   => 'B',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'service_provider_tier',
    'meta_type' => 'CHAR',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $supplierArgs );

This approach uses meta_value to order the posts and assigns the custom field service_provider_tier to meta_key. It orders the results by the value of the service_provider_tier meta key. If you need a custom order (Gold, Silver, Basic), you may have to manipulate the query results after fetching them or use a custom sorting function.
